# Proof A=C or B=C

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A,B,C are sets
we know P(A)∪P(B)=P(C)
and we need to prove A=C or B=C

my way:
we know P(A)∪P(B)=P(C) so
P(A)∪P(B)⊆P(C) and P(C)⊆P(A)∪P(B)

P(A)∪P(B)⊆P(C)
we know A⊆A and B⊆B so A∈P(A) and B∈P(B) so A∈P(C) and B∈P(C) so A⊆C and B⊆C

P(C)⊆P(A)∪P(B)
the same way we get:
C⊆A and C⊆B

and then we get A=C and B=C which is different (but still proofs) from what we need to proof.
Am I wrong anywhere?
thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of it looks good to me. However, the statement $C \subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B$ isn't true. Try working through that section explicitly and you'll see that you actually get $C \subseteq A$ *or* $C \subseteq B$, giving the desired result $A = C$ or $B = C$.